# Calling AlertDialog with listitems from menu

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-menu, multiple-choice

I want to have a menu item clicked and than show an alert-dialog with multiple choice for the selection of one or more items to do something.
I tried already many examples from different tutorials but none really suits my needs.
The task should start here:
[image: main menu with task items]

The user opens the menu from main activity and select the item to delete a category.

Until now I get an alert-dialog like this:
[image: The alert dialog which pops up]

The MainActivity is defined like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,
    AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener,SearchView.OnQueryTextListener,SearchView.OnCloseListener {
```

Here is the source code of the option menu:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_clear_all:
            clearDoneItems();
            this.items_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
        case R.id.action_select_all:
            selectAllItems();
            this.items_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;

        case R.id.action_delete_done_items:
            deleteDoneItems();
            break;

        case R.id.action_delete_all:
            deleteAllItems();
            break;

        case R.id.action_add_category:
            add_category("");
            break;
        case R.id.action_delete_category:
            del_category();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is the current methode I call to delete one or more selected items:

```
    public void del_category() {
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    View dialogView = li.inflate(android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice, null);

/* wb, 31Oct2017: preparation for list in delete categories */
    final ArrayList<Integer> sList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String[] delCats = new String[list_categories.size()];
    boolean iCount[] = new boolean[delCats.length];
    String msg ="";
    for (int i = 0; i == list_categories.size(); i++) {
        if (!list_categories.get(i).getSpinnerCategory().equals(" PLEASE SELECT A CATEGORY"))
        {delCats[i] = list_categories.get(i).getSpinnerCategory();}
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(dialogView)
            .setTitle("Delete categories")
            .setMessage("Please select categories to be deleted")
            .setMultiChoiceItems(delCats, iCount, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
                            if (arg2) {
                                sList.add(arg1);
                            } else if (sList.contains(arg1)) {
                                // if the item is already selected then remove it
                                sList.remove(Integer.valueOf(arg1));
                            }
                        }
                    }
            )
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton
                    (
                            "Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "So far", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                    )
            .setNegativeButton
                    ("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Option Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                    );
    //Creating dialog box
    AlertDialog dialog  = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
}
```

I am very new to android programming and so I guess there is not all done very well. Let me just explain some special things I did here:

The reason why I fill a list "delCats[]" is the original source ("list_categories") with all the categories saved from an xml-file is defined from a class I made called "CategoryTask.java". But the "builder.setMultiChoiceItems()"-method will not accept such a type for the first parameter. Therefore I use the loop to take over the categories to a list "delCats".

The first item of the categories (" PLEASE SELECT ...") will not take over. It is not a real category and only existing because the user should forced to select the right category for an item before he can save it.

I hope someone here can let me now what I made wrong and why I do not see any category with the right checkbox. I even can not click to the one checkbox which is to be seen.

During a debug session I can see that all items in delCat are available and also all values for the checkboxes are set to "false" in the boolean array "icount".

Many thanks in advance Andreas

Edit:
I changed the for-loop. As you can see "delCats' and "iCount" have filled in the right way. But there are still no changes in the result:
[image]

Edit 2:
I do not see that there is something wrong with the for-loop in the method. Even when I changed it to the suggestion from the comment to my post the App is crashing.

I showed it already with the screen shots above:
The loop now is working fine and the values for delCat and iCount have been filled correct. So the problem muist be in another part. 
[image]

A debugging shows the app is crashing when it comes to dialog.show(); statement.
Another interesting thing: If I use a string array which I filled at runtime insted of using the for-loop with delCats I was able to create an alert. 
So I guess the types must be different, but I have no idea why. And the output is not what I wanted to see. It is only a list but with no checkboxes and I could only click to one item.
[image: using a manual filled string array]

So you see there are still some problems and still I have no solution found for that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a list inside the adapter and set the list as items instead of setMultiChoiceItems.

Create a alertDialog and add listItems inside it.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
 alertBuilder.setTitle("Select A Item ");
 alertBuilder.setItems(delCats, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         String selectedText= Arrays.asList(value).get(which);
      }
 });

AlertDialog dialog = alertBuilder.create();
dialog.show();
```

**EDIT**:
Seeing you code it is clear that the String Array for loop is wrong.`i == list_categories.size()`  makes the loop run only once and items are not added except the first one.

```
for (int i = 0; i == list_categories.size(); i++)
```

change `i == list_categories.size()`  to

```
for (int i = 0; i <= list_categories.size(); i++)
```

**EDIT 2:** The problem with your code is again the for loop.The loop is giving index out of bounds.You should use either

```
  for (int i = 0; i <= list_categories.size(); i++)
```

OR

```
   for (int i = 0; i < list_categories.size()-1; i++)
```

Loop always runs from 0 because i starts from zero but it will point to the first item of the arraylist.So for `i=list_categories.size()` the index will be out of the arraylist and throws index out of bond error.So change it to  `list_categories.size()-1`.

Comment: Hi many thanks for your suggestions. I edit the post in that way. The For-Loop only works with "<" not with "<=". It might be coz I do not take the firlst item.
Your sample code looks interesting. Unfortunatelly I do not know what to set for "vale" in "Array.asList(value)...". Could you please give me a hint?

Comment: The problem with your code was "==" in the for loop.I think "<=" or "<" should have solved your problem.Regarding that sample code I thought your are making the multiple selection using long press on list..For now your code is fine and should work great.your are having any problems again?

Comment: Yes I have. I will not do a long press. As I sowed with the screen shots the user should click/touch to the menu item, the alert should pop up, the user should select one or more categories and then click th positiv button to delete the categories. As of now it is still like it was before. And still I do not understand what you mean with "value" in "Arrays.asList(value).get(which)".
My app stopps as of now when it comes to "dialog.show" and I can not see the reason when I run the debugger. Sorry!

Comment: leave "value" part...do the changes I said in edit2..for sure your dialog will work

Comment: Hi again!
I very much appreciate what you try to solve my problem. Unfortunately I guess you are wrong thinking the problem is with the loop. You could not know but I am new to Android but I have a long experiences in programming. So I am pretty sure to know about loops.

If you like - I hope so - please see my new editing to the post.
Andreas